# Jackson JsonSchemaGenerator - How to get Schema as String

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I'm sure I'm just being dense here.

I want to take an object schema, and turn it into a string representation.

Like so, but this returns null:

```
JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(MAPPER);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(Get.class);
System.out.println("jsonSchema: " + jsonSchema.asObjectSchema().asStringSchema());
```

This is using com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema, found at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/wiki

Answer (score 11):

you can achieve that by doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(mapper.constructType(YOURCLASS.class), visitor);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
String schemaString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily done:

```
m.writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
```

Essentially, using Jackson to marshal the schema object into JSON.